# Jquery can't use 3 selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm writing a small script to make a mobile menu.

However I can't get my selectors to work together.

When I have `$('#nav_button, .nav li, .nav li li')` only `#nav_button and .nav li` works, however when I remove `.nav li` and leave `$('#nav_button, .nav li li')` this sub menu begins to work as well.
I have also tried using `$('#nav_button, .nav li, .sub_menu li li')` with the same results.

Does anyone have an idea why?

jquery:

```
var mobileMenu = function () {

    var currentPosition = 'closed'
    $('#nav_button, .nav li, .nav li li').click(function() {

        if (currentPosition == 'closed') {
            $('.nav').addClass('open');
            currentPosition = 'open';
        }
        else {
            $('.nav').removeClass('open');
            currentPosition = 'closed';
        }
    });
};
```

html:

```
<div id="head">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="cover"></div>
            <a href="#"><h1 class="logo pull-left">C<span class="logo_space">AV</span>O</h1>
            </a> <!-- end logo !-->
            <div id="nav_button"></div>
            <ul class="nav pull-right">
                <li><a href="#menu">Menu</a>
                    <ul class="sub_menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Starters</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Breakfast and Brunch</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Salads</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sandwiches and Wraps</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Pasta</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Mains</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Pizza</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- end container !-->
    </div> <!-- end header !-->
```

Comment: These three are different type of Descantant selectors

Comment: I have also tried ".nav LI UL LI" with no effect if that helps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, two of your selectors match the same elements

```
$('#nav_button, .nav li, .nav li li')
```

`.nav li` matches any LI inside `.nav`, including nested LI's
`.nav li li` matches any LI's inside `.nav` that are inside another LI, i.e. nested LI's

In other words, LI elements inside LI elements, inside `.nav` are matched twice, but it shouldn't matter as jQuery removes duplicates, but it's uneccessary.

The real issue is that the event propagates, when you click a nested LI the event handler is called for the nested LI **and** the parent LI, so the click handler execute twice, and the class is first added, then removed (or vice versa) so there is no visible change.

Here's a simplified example

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/hc0unum9/1/)

Just doing

```
$('#nav_button, .nav li')
```

should be enough, but you **have to add** `event.stopPropagation()` to make sure the event doesn't propagate to the next parent LI when a LI is called, here's an example

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/hc0unum9/2/)

```
$('#nav_button, .nav li').on('click', function(e) {
     e.stopPropagation();

     // do stuff
});
```

Comment: This worked perfectly thank you! Can you expand on this propagation function? whats happening here exactly?

Comment: It stops the event from bubbling up the DOM tree. Some events bubbles, that is when you click a child element, the click propagates to all it's parents, all the way up to the document level. In your case you want to stop that propagation so as to not fire the event handler multiple times.

Comment: I did some reading myself, if I understand correctly, because it is the child, it would close and then the parent li would reopen it immediately making it appear as if its not working at all?

Comment: Yes, the event handlers trigger twice as the click is picked up on two elements, and as the event handler is a "toggle" function of sorts, it toggles twice, making it so the first change is zeroed out by the second change.

Answer (score 1):

As @adeneo said in nested li function will call twice unnecessarily. I think the other way to achieve this is divide click grabber in two selectors like below:

```
$('.nav').click(function() {

    if (currentPosition == 'closed') {
        alert('open');
        $('.nav').addClass('open');
        currentPosition = 'open';
    }
    else {
        alert('close');
        $(this).removeClass('open');
        currentPosition = 'closed';
    }
});

$('.nav > li > li').click(function() {

    if (currentPosition == 'closed') {
        alert('open');
        $(this).addClass('open');
        currentPosition = 'open';
    }
    else {
        alert('close');
        $('.nav').removeClass('open');
        currentPosition = 'closed';
    }
});
```

I wrote a fiddle to do what you expect. Please check and comment if that helpful.

http://jsfiddle.net/QMaster/y7d6osoq/

Comment: While this would work, I essentially asked the question to avoid this scenario.

Comment: @flo So excuse me. Because of you didn't mention it, I didn't know about that. Anyway thanks for your heeds and I think more than one answer maybe useful to extend meaning of discussion.

Comment: i didn't mean offence sorry.

Comment: @flo Don't. I'm Sure you hadn't, and I didn't conceive it as  offence. Thanks man :)